# how to query rdf file with sparql in jena

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena

I want to query an rdf file with sparql in jena. the rdf file is as follow:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73"
     xmlns:swp2="http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#"
     xmlns:untitled-ontology-73="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#"
     xmlns:protege="http://protege.stanford.edu/plugins/owl/protege#"
     xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
     xmlns:xsp="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/2005/08/07/xsp.owl#"
     xmlns:ns66675="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
     xmlns:cmp="http://ld.thomsonreuters.com/ContentMarketplace/2013-10-15/#"
     xmlns:ns36343="http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/umls/"
     xmlns:Ontology1395931632451="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2014/2/Ontology1395931632451.owl#"
     xmlns:ns20477="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:ns28717="http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/HL7/"
     xmlns:ns91299="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:schema="http://schema.org/"
     xmlns:swrl="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#"
     xmlns:owl2xml="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/owl2-xml#"
     xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
     xmlns:admin="http://webn.net/mvcb/"
     xmlns:mds="http://ld.thomsonreuters.com/MetadataSystems/2013-10-15/#"
     xmlns:swrlb="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrlb#"
     xmlns:base="http://ld.thomsonreuters.com/MetadataSystems/2013-10-15/"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <ns91299:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Object Properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#knowns -->

    <ns91299:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#knowns">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#ReflexiveProperty"/>
        <ns20477:range rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#person"/>
        <ns20477:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#person"/>
    </ns91299:ObjectProperty>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Data properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#name -->

    <ns91299:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#name">
        <ns20477:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#person"/>
        <ns20477:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
    </ns91299:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#person -->

    <ns91299:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#person">
        <ns20477:subClassOf>
            <ns91299:Restriction>
                <ns91299:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#knowns"/>
                <ns91299:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#person"/>
            </ns91299:Restriction>
        </ns20477:subClassOf>
    </ns91299:Class>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Individuals
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#amina -->

    <ns91299:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#amina">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#person"/>
        <name>amina</name>
        <knowns rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#george"/>
        <knowns rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#john"/>
    </ns91299:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#george -->

    <ns91299:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#george">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#person"/>
        <name>george</name>
        <knowns rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#amina"/>
        <knowns rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#nacira"/>
    </ns91299:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#john -->

    <ns91299:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#john">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#person"/>
        <name>john</name>
    </ns91299:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#nacira -->

    <ns91299:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#nacira">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#person"/>
        <name>nacira</name>
    </ns91299:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>



<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 3.4.5-SNAPSHOT) http://owlapi.sourceforge.net -->
```

The java code is as follow:

```
package firstProject;

import java.util.Iterator;
//import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
//import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Literal;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    sparqltest();}

static void sparqltest()
{

    FileManager.get().addLocatorClassLoader(main.class.getClassLoader());
    Model model= FileManager.get().loadModel("C:/Users/acer/workspace/firstProject/src/firstProject/onto1.rdf");

String queryString=
       "PREFIX rdf:<http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#>"+
             "SELECT * WHERE {"+
      "?person foaf:name ?x. "+
          "?person foaf:knows ?person2."+
          "?person2 foaf:name ?y."+
       "FILTER( ?y = \"john\")"+
       "}";
Query query= QueryFactory.create(queryString);
QueryExecution qexec=QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
try {
    ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();while ( results.hasNext()){
        QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution();
        Literal name = soln.getLiteral("x");
        System.out.println(name);
    }
} finally {
qexec.close();
    }}}
```

I can't execute this query beacause there is an a lot of error:
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.jena.riot.stream.JenaIOEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

I hope someone will help me on this.

Thx?

Comment: You forgot to include your code and your query.

Comment: Why is there a second `PREFIX` with no prefix specified?

Comment: I have found this code on the web but it don't work!

Comment: You might be missing a space after the first prefix declaration. Don't know the SPARQL specifications exactly. What error do you get?

Comment: I've delated the second prefix but it don't work

Comment: errors are as follow:

Comment: I have followed a tutorial presented here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUdHneViLp4

Comment: the secont prefix is: "PREFIX foaf:<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>"

Comment: so add the foaf prefix. and add newlines "\n" at least after each prefix

Comment: Yes I've add it but It still an error: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.jena.riot.stream.JenaIOEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: these error are the same on the tutorial. my query normaly must return "Amina" as result.

Comment: Those are just warnings and should not harm the execution of the query. Do you get a reasonable result?

Comment: Non I have not got any result. the result of the query must be: "Amina"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your RDF file, the `knows` property uses the default namespace, which is set to `http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#` in that file's prefix declarations. In your query, however, you are using the property `foaf:knows`. In your example code this prefix is not declared in your query (and therefore the query is incorrect), but I see in the comments that you've added a prefix declaration for it later (tip: update your question).

So, you have properties `http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#knows` in your database, but you query for `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows`. See the problem? Everything works fine, you're just querying for the wrong property.

On a more general note: simply copy-pasting code from the web is not really the best way to learn how to use these tools. I suggest you work your way through one of the Jena tutorials which teach you a bit more about the how and why. This will make your life a lot easier in the longer run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you're right. I have replaced foaf by rdf       
"PREFIX rdf:<http://www.semanticweb.org/acer/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-73#>"+
//"PREFIX foaf:<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>"+
   "SELECT * WHERE {"+
      "?person rdf:name ?x "+
  
       "}";

Comment: but why this query don't return any result?  "SELECT * WHERE {"+
      "?person rdf:name ?x "+
  // "?person rdf:knows ?person2."+
   //"?person2 rdf:name ?y."+
       //"FILTER( ?y = \"john\")"+
       "}";

Comment: Because you have defined rdf: to be something different to the data.

Comment: I have replaced knowns by knowns in the rdf file so the query return now the correct result. thanks Jeen for your - Thanks for the explanation.